# Is it correct to say that H2SO4 is an acid in this reaction?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

Is it correct to say that $\ce{H2SO_4}$ acts as an acid in the following reaction?

$\ce{2Ag + H2SO_4} \rightarrow \ce{Ag_2SO_4 + 2H_2O + SO_2}$

I know it acts as an oxidizing agent, but is it correct to say it shows acidic properties?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you get the same reaction with sodium sulfate?

I do not think so, at least under "normal" conditions.

When the sulfuric acid acts as an oxidizing agent giving off $\ce{SO_2}$, the excess oxygen comes off as oxide ions which must be somehow put into more stable form.  The protons from the sulphuric **acid** do that by turning them to water.

Getting the reaction to go requires the sulfuric acid to act as both an acid and an oxidizing agent.